# What happens when I change Azure Functions App Settings during function execution

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Let's say I change the DaysToSync value in Azure Portal App Settings during execution.

```cs
[FunctionName(DateRangeFunctionNames.GetSyncDateRangeActivity)]
 public DateRange GetSyncDateRange(
     [ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context)
 {
     var startDate = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(configuration.DaysToSync()).Date;
     var endDate = DateTimeOffset.Now.Date;

     return new DateRange(startDate, endDate);
 }
```

Will that affect currently running functions which use this one?

Comment: The Function will restart and when the ActivityTrigger is triggered, the new setting will be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer is, yes**, it will affect the function which uses the setting.

It will take the latest value of the setting next time you hit the function.

I validated this on the Azure portal and each time I changed the `App Setting` value while keeping the function app running, **it took the updated value** upon the next time the trigger was hit.